# Compare two cells of different columns and shift down the greater value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two cells of different columns and shift the greater number downward and then compare with another number.

[Initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZiAy.png)
[Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZQ1g.png)

I tried this:

```vb
Sub compare()
Dim n As Integer

n = Worksheets("Compare").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To n
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Then Next i
    Else
        If Cells(i, 1).Value > Cells(i, 3).Value Then
            Range("A", i).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Else
            Range("C", i).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but got stuck with work. However, since I like playing around with arrays, here's my answer that takes in account the issues Lord-JulianXLII had with Black Cat's answer:

```
Sub compare()
    Dim lRow As Long, lRowC As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Compare")
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lRowC = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim arrA: arrA = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
    Dim arrC: arrC = ws.Range("C1:C" & lRowC).Value
    Dim arrANew, arrCNew, rCountA As Long, rCountC As Long, i As Long, j As Long, maxRows As Long, n As Long, k As Long
    maxRows = lRow + lRowC
    ReDim arrANew(1 To maxRows, 1 To 1)
    ReDim arrCNew(1 To maxRows, 1 To 1)
    i = 1 'keeps track what A-number we're on in arrA
    j = 1 'keeps track what C-number we're on in arrC
    While n <= maxRows
        n = n + 1
        If arrA(i, 1) = arrC(j, 1) Then
            arrANew(n, 1) = arrA(i, 1)
            arrCNew(n, 1) = arrC(j, 1)
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
        ElseIf arrA(i, 1) < arrC(j, 1) Then
            arrANew(n, 1) = arrA(i, 1)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            arrCNew(n, 1) = arrC(j, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        If i > lRow Then
            If j > lRowC Then
                rCountA = n
                rCountC = n
            Else
                rCountA = n
                For k = j To lRowC 'fininshing off the C-column since A-column is done
                    n = n + 1
                    arrCNew(n, 1) = arrC(k, 1)
                Next k
                rCountC = n
            End If
            GoTo skipWhile
        End If
        If j > lRowC Then 'finish off the A-column
            rCountC = n
            For k = i To lRow
                n = n + 1
                arrANew(n, 1) = arrA(k, 1)
            Next k
            rCountA = n
            GoTo skipWhile
        End If
        GoTo skipSkip
skipWhile:
        n = maxRows + 1
skipSkip:
    Wend
    
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(rCountA) = arrANew
    ws.Range("C1").Resize(rCountC) = arrCNew
        
End Sub
```

Even adding a 15 at the end or having an empty cell doesn't cause any issues. Only thing I didn't know if it was meant to be that way or any different is with an empty cell, does it need an empty cell next to it?
Regardless, this should be able to handle bigger ranges due to working with arrays :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the followings

- Range parameters must be defined in another way then Cells parameter.
- When insert a cell in column A the `n` value should be increased.
- For loop cannot modify end value, therefore changed to Do loop.
- Dont't forget to reset ScreenUpdating
- Cannot use two `Next` for one `For`

Try this with your data

**Edit**
on Lord-JulianXLII comments.

```
Sub compare()
Dim n As Integer

n = Worksheets("Compare").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Do Until i > n
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Then
    Else
        If Cells(i, 1).Value > Cells(i, 3).Value And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
             Cells(i, "A").Select
             Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
             n = n + 1
        Else
             Cells(i, "C").Select
             Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
    DoEvents
Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After finish testing remove DoEvents.

Comment: Multiple issues with this answer: You are skipping the last iteration (the condition should be `i <= n`) - You also created an infinite loop since empty Cells have the numerical value 0. This can lead to n and i both being increased by one in every single iteration (making it an infinite loop) - to try this out just add a 15 to the left column

Comment: If you fix the skipping of the last iteration and add a guard clause that exits the loop if one of the Cells is empty then this answer should work fine.